# Updating colors of plot_model when I have only a single line?

Tags: r

I want to change the color of the plot outputted by plot_model. I have no trouble with these when I create multiple lines by including multiple variables in terms = c(..., ...), but I can't get the color to be anything other than black when I do the following code:

```
df_test <- data.frame('subj' = c('Joe', 'Joe', 'Moe', 'Moe'), 'A' = c(1, 0, 1, 0), 'B' = c(3, 2, 1, 4))

m = glmer(A ~ B + (B | subj), data=df_test, family='binomial')

print(plot_model(m, type='pred', colors = 'blue'))
```

Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm8YT.jpg

What am I missing here?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Which package(s) are you using? `lme4` I guess, and?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform this action, I modified the structure for `data.frame` and I used `ggplot2`.

```
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(sjPlot)
df_test <- data.frame('subj' = c('Joe', 'Joe', 'Moe', 'Moe'), 'A' = c(1, 0, 1, 0), 'B' = c(3, 2, 1, 4))

m <- lme4::glmer(A ~ B + (B | subj), data=df_test, family='binomial')

p <- sjPlot::plot_model(m, type='pred', colors = 'blue')

df <- as.data.frame(p$B$data)
df
ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), fill = "grey70") +
  geom_line(aes(y = predicted), col = "blue") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent,
                     limits = c(0, 1))
```

[image]

```
ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), 
              fill = "deepskyblue", alpha = 0.25) +
  geom_line(aes(y = predicted), col = "darkred") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent,
                     limits = c(0, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Welp, this seems a bit clunkier than what I was hoping for, but it certainly works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ggeffects-package](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/), which is internally used by *sjPlot* when creating marginal effects plots. This makes it a bit easier getting the data and then using ggplot:

```r
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
library(ggeffects)
library(ggplot2)
#> Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'ggplot2':
#>   method         from 
#>   [.quosures     rlang
#>   c.quosures     rlang
#>   print.quosures rlang

df_test <- data.frame('subj' = c('Joe', 'Joe', 'Moe', 'Moe'), 'A' = c(1, 0, 1, 0), 'B' = c(3, 2, 1, 4))
m<- glmer(A ~ B + (B | subj), data=df_test, family='binomial')
#> boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular

ggpredict(m, "B") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, predicted)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), alpha = .2) +
  geom_line(colour = "blue")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

There are several examples for manually building plots, e.g. [here](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/ggeffects.html) or [here](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/index.html).

Comment: But why can't sjPlot::plot_model() just take a simple color argument? the package has so many other customization options that it is weird you can't do something as simple as change a line color